# What is this strange tree?

Tags: identification, trees

We recently bought a new house, and it came with various trees scattered around the yard.  We've managed to identify all but one of them.  At first we thought it looked kind of like a plum tree, but then a local landscaping professional looked at it with my wife and said she didn't know what it was but it's definitely not a plum.  Today my wife was pruning the trees and she found long, thin spines growing from the branches, which leads her to suspect that it might be a *wild olive tree,* of all things!

After looking the tree over, neither of us can see any fruit of any kind growing on it.

Can anyone help identify what this is?

Tree:
[image]

Pruned branches, showing the spines:
[image]

Comment: I've seen "long hard spikes" only on plum and pear. The leaves don't look like either to me. Can't You just wait for 12 months and see what gets?

Answer (score 1):

Apricots. The thorns are spikes as evolutionary features. If the leaves don't resemble like an Apricot I'm sure that it'll be some plant in Ziziphus family. More probably a Jujube or Indian ber.

[Wikipedia- Ber/ Indian Jujube](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ziziphus_mauritiana)

Comment: It would help your answer if you are able to provide a reference or a link to an authority or if you can provide photos of your tree.

Comment: @RohitGupta Reference 1: https://growingfruit.org/t/thorns-on-apricot/24861      Reference 2: https://khkeeler.blogspot.com/2018/07/plant-story-adaptable-apricots.html?m=1